# Automated removal of unneeded packages

Tags: packages, scripts

As others certainly do, I generally use a template for my papers, which contains everything I usually need (packages, macros, ...) to typeset my documents. However, my needs sometimes vary, and in the end I find myself including packages that I did not need.

What I generally do in the preamble is `\usepackage{P} % R`, where R is the reason (e.g. set of commands) for including package P. This then allows me to check that R applies to my document, and remove P if not, but this is still a rather tedious process. Does anyone know of a script that checks for unneeded packages or commands in a document?

Answer (score 4):

If you have Linux (or some other system where to run bash and gnu-version on grep), make a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

> notneeded
> needed

fgrep '\usepackage' $1 | cut -f 2 -d '{' | cut -f 1 -d '}' |
while read a; do
    egrep -v "\\usepackage(\[.+\])?\{$a\}" $1 > tmp.tex
    latex -halt-on-error tmp.tex &&
        echo $a >> notneeded || echo $a >> needed
done
```

If you save this as `unused.sh`, run it with `unused.sh mydoc.tex` and you will get file called `notneeded`.

This breaks if you have, say, two `\usepackage` in same line. That can be corrected with `-o` to grep. However, more complicated situations are usually better done with perl.

E: There is more to think. First, there might be unused tikzlibaries. You might have `\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}` where `arrows` is needes but `shapes` is not.

Then, some packages are used but not "needed" as "does not compile without", for example `microtype`. OK, you can check if document changes at all when you remove a package, but then, hypersetup put ModDate to PDF metadata.

Answer (score 3):

no not possible, unless you wrote a script which collects *all* commands and environments from the packages and compare it with your document.

Answer (score 1):

Patching `\newcommand` to keep a record of what has been defined by what package, and what has been used, might work here but I'm not sure it's worth the effort.  Just don't include so much. Or, live with a few more unecessary milliseconds of compile time.

Comment: `\newcommand`, `\def`, `\edef`, `\gdef`, `\xdef`, `\protected@edef`, `\def\mynewcommand{...` aso and counters, boxes, tokens, dimens ...

Comment: Well, probably just `\def`, `\edef`, `\xdef`, and `\gdef`. the others eventually expand to those 4.

Comment: "eventually" ...

Comment: I think you could get 95% of what the OP wanted by patching `\newcommand` since most LaTeX packages will provide top-level commands this way.  But like I said, I'm *not* recommending this.

Comment: then let us compare a real latex package like `hyperref`, which doesn't work with TeX: `\newcommand`  29 and 
`\def` 1701